# How are words with no other context used as greetings or partings?

Tags: interjections

I happen to be aware that "goodbye" or "bye bye" derives from "May God be with you". However, most English speakers that I have asked seem to not know this. When asked "What does 'bye bye' mean?" they will not know. It seems that the word "bye", due to being used in no other context in English, is a sort of nonsense word that people use out of habit with no ulterior intention or expression of meaning. Contrast this with Russian, Hebrew, or other languages in which the greetings and partings are words or phrases with real meanings, such as "peace [to you]".

How is it that some languages or cultures will accept words for greetings and partings that have no obvious meaning? Is the usage of these words simply learned from the surroundings with no questions asked as to the meanings? Are there other words that people use in which they do not know the meaning?

Comment: How can you say that English speakers don't know what "bye bye" means? Of course they know: it's a leavetaking expression. You're saying that they don't know its origin, which is a different thing altogether and has little to do with its current meaning. There are also synchronically transparent leavetakings in English, such as: "see you later", "sleep well", "until we meet again", etc.

Comment: Thank you Gaston. The phrase "see you later" means "may there be visual contact between us again in the future. However, in what other context might the word "bye" from "bye bye" be used? It is to this that I am referring. I will edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: BTW, sorry for the linguistic jargon, sometimes it flows out my fingers without me thinking about it!

Comment: Actually, Gaston, I thank you for using the jargon. I come here quite to learn it!

Comment: That's great to hear. If you're not sure what [synchronic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronic_analysis) means, I've linked it to a good explanation on WP.

Comment: This seems a good time to start pointing people to [this addition to the FAQ](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/388/363), which is intended to help people understand linguistic terminology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I feel you're artificially limiting yourself to greetings when you could ask a similar question of all words.

Second, there's a fundemental flaw in your question in that you assume the origin of a word has a large effect on its meaning. As counter-intuitive as it may seem, etymology isn't particularly useful in most linguistic studies. Does knowing that "Thursday" has its root in the Norse god ["Thor"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thursday) truly effect your understanding of what "Thursday" means?

Furthermore, small, incremental changes gathered over long periods of time can yield words with meanings completely dettached from their original source. The word "hysterical" meaning "very funny" can trace its origin back through "excessively emotional" all the way back to the Greek word for ["womb"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hysterical&allowed_in_frame=0). Obviously the modern meaning of "hysterical" has little to do with wombs!

Another mistake you're making is that you assume these greetings are context-free. In fact, their usage is strictly bound by a rich context! No native English speaker would ever randomly say "bye bye" except in the context of a parting phrase (specifically, a parting phrase offered to someone who the speaker is highly familiar with or by/to someone who is very young). Humans don't learn language the same way they learn math. Humans learn language passively through observation, mimicry, deduction, intuition, and trial and error with very little directed input or overt effort (at least as children). Basically, to children the **what** doesn't matter nearly as much as the **when and how**.

As for why some languages use a phrase and some languages use a word, if you spend any time trying to learn a second language you will quickly discover words in that language that take an entire sentence to explain in English and vice versa. In fact, this is why loanwords exist; words and phrases adopted from other languages because they express an idea more efficiently than pure native vocabulary alone ever could. The reasons for this can be historical or cultural or it could just be down to plain chance.

Even in languages where their greetings are explicitly phrases, my experience is that they become almost a reflex and few speakers stop to consider the literal meaning. For example, I am currently learning Korean and the standard Korean greeting, some variation of "안녕하세요!" (*annyeonghasaeyo*, literally ["be peaceful"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%95%88%EB%85%95) or "peace be with you"), is so dettached from it's literal meaning that if one tried to use the word "안녕" (*annyeong*) to remark that something is peaceful or tranquil they would be met with slight confusion.

Comment: *"First, I feel you're artificially limiting yourself to greetings when you could ask a similar question of all words."* I was thinking this earlier today!

Comment: Thank you acattle. You touch upon a few subjects here and answer some other questions that I had wanted to ask but not yet asked! This truly is a great answer. I suppose the issue is that in modern Hebrew I believe that we do not have any words that are confined to any single context. In fact, the Biblical words that were confined to a single context were very problematic as to discerning their meaning, and I suppose that leaves an impression on the modern language, and influences my sensitivity to words with only a single context in any language. Your "Thursday" example makes this clear.

Comment: @dotandcohen Ah, I think part of your problem is that Modern Hebrew is a bit of a special case. I've spoken a lot with an Israeli friend about this and from what he says Modern Hebrew is somewhat of an artificial language. Sure, it's based on Biblical Hebrew but because for a time it was only spoken in synagogue, Modern Hebrew had to be "rebuilt" to be able to handle modern concepts (like computers, etc.). So Modern Hebrew is largely the result of one big, purposeful language change. Compared with English, which is the result of hundreds of years of smaller, accidental changes.

Comment: Very much so. I suppose that the rebuilding processes made sure that every word has well-defined meaning. Thus not-well-defined meanings stick out for us in other languages. I wonder how that fact affects other fields, such as mathematics.

Comment: @dotancohen I imagine it's more the opposite and Hebrew meanings are more broadly defined. The limited vocabulary in Biblical Hebrew had to be modified to deal with situations and objects that don't exist in the Bible. That could explain why Modern Hebrew has few words that only have a single context. Just remember, I have not studied Hebrew so I'm just guessing.